# RabbitMQ Client connect to several hosts

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, failover, failovercluster

The main goal to have several hosts of RabbiMQ servers ([clustering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)) 
Are there any best practices to implement having several RabbitMQ hosts, and reconnect to the next one in case previous connection closed.

Tutorial says that:

> A client can connect as normal to any node within a cluster. If that
>   node should fail, and the rest of the cluster survives, then the
>   client should notice the closed connection, and should be able to
>   reconnect to some surviving member of the cluster. Generally, it's not
>   advisable to bake in node hostnames or IP addresses into client
>   applications

How it can be implemented from the client side ?

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this typical problem is configure an load-balancer (it's enough in roud-robin configuration ) for your cluster (like [HAPROXY](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), [cross-road](http://crossroads.e-tunity.com/) ..or others) .

> client(s)--->ip-load-balacer--brokerS

In this way you can use **only** the load-balancer IP in your client(s) connection.

For having more flexibility you can add a DNS (local dns) bound to the load balancer, in this way you can also change the balancer without change the client configuration.

> client(s)--->-load-balacer-DNSNAME--brokerS

If one client lose the connection you have to re-coonect it to the same ip or dns.

You should have an HA client for c# like [this](https://github.com/jhalterman/lyra) for java, or simply manage the connection shutdown event.

Say that, if you have a small and static cluster you could use the IP(s) from the client side.

From the client side (if you want handle only the disconnect):

```
connection = connection = factory.CreateConnection();
channel = connection.CreateModel();
.......
connection.ConnectionShutdown += Connection_ConnectionShutdown;

 void Connection_ConnectionShutdown(IConnection connection, ShutdownEventArgs reason)
{
    Console.WriteLine("connection_ConnectionShutdown " + reason.ToString());
    Reconnect_client();
}
```